# Drawing 3D points from external file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a file which has x,y and z coordinates:

```
4   1   0
9   3   0
9   9   0
3   5   10
0   3   10
9   0   10
1   6   20
9   9   20
1   4   20
7   2   20
10  1   30
4   3   30
3   6   30
```

I need to scatter them as small spheres in 3D with TikZ.  This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfplots,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [   view={-45}{60},
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    zmin=0, zmax=10,
    ]
    \addplot3[scatter] coordinates {./a.dat};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near './a.dat'. Please check for format mistakes. \addplot3 coordinates {./a.dat};
```

As @ferahfeza suggested, I tried `\addplot3 [scatter] table[] {./a.dat};`, but I get the following.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete example we can compile to reproduce the error. Fragments aren't generally anywhere near as useful.

Comment: @cfr I have edited the question to give a complete example. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: Try `\addplot3 [scatter] table[] {./a.dat};`

Comment: Do you want the scatter plot without lines between points?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ferahfeza's comment, I was able to figure out the way to solve my problem.

The correct command is to put `scatter` argument along with `only marks`, and use the keyword `file` before the file name:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfplots,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [   view={-45}{60},
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
    zmin=0, zmax=10,
    ]
    \addplot3[scatter, only marks] file{./a.dat};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is usual to ask the person who helped to write an answer, rather than taking the credit yourself! If that doesn't work (e.g. the commenter is no longer around), a community wiki answer is generally the best solution.

Comment: How can I convert my answer to a community wiki answer? I do not believe the comments helped me a lot.

Comment: If they didn't help much but just gave a hint, say, then edit your answer to just link to the comment by way of acknowledgement. I thought the answer was basically what was in the comment, but I was obviously mistaken so I apologise. A complete example in your answer would be good, too. (Complete examples make it easier for other users to learn from your answer, in the same way that complete examples make it easier for people to answer your questions :-).)