# 3D Polar Plot in sperical coordinate system in PGF/Tikz - Matlab2tikz fails, me too. (CST MWS Antenna FarField pattern)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, matlab, matlab2tikz

I have simulated an Antenna in CST and want to plot the 3D pattern. The resolution is fairly low with a step size of 20°.
Matlab2tikz won't help because it creates huge PDFs (60kB tex file to 5MB incorrect PDF).
I have been working on this issue several times over the past 4 year and eventually I have created an account here to seek for help.

I have added the data that I want to plot: [txt file containing the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jti3v3f87lahqfx/test.txt?dl=0)
Hereby I am mainly interested in the first 3 columns. The remaining columns are the components of the complex field that I calculated.

Until now I had to use the png plots from Matlab, but I use tikz and pgf for everything (I'm a noob but I use it) so I finally want to get it done. Please help.
Since this is my first question I guess I did a fair amount of mistakes, so thank for ignoring them.

Kind regards
Homo

UPDATE:

This is the [tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9koq2amrmbm3uhc/test.tex?dl=0) file and this is the resulting [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc5maxaj3e22yvm/test.pdf?dl=0), and this is how it should look [like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/98xuhjr5sm36fm0/test.png?dl=0).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! To plot that many points, it's probably best to parse the file and produce something that tikz can understand (this is non-tikz and non-latex issue). Have you tried plotting anything, like a single point in 3D? Perhaps [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390161/drawing-3d-points-from-external-file) is a good starting point.

Comment: Could you please show us how the result should roughly look like? There are various ways to plot things, especially in 3d.

Comment: I updated the question with the tex file, the resulting pdf, and the png from Matlab, kind regards.